# RegEx pattern for partial URL (switch on two values in path)

Tags: c#, regex

I have a URL pattern that needs to contain either APPLES or ORANGES in it, no other value. Optionally, it can also have query parameters. I've tried a number of RegEx patterns, but I just can't get a pattern that will respect the strict match.

**Sample URLs**

***Good***

```
http://www.website.com/en/pages/APPLES
http://www.website.com/en/pages/APPLES?k=v
http://www.website.com/en/pages/ORANGES?k=v&k2=v2
http://www.website.com/en/pages/ORANGES
```

***Bad***

```
http://www.website.com/en/pages/APPLES???k=v
http://www.website.com/en/pages/APPLES?k=v=v
http://www.website.com/en/pages/APPLESORANGES
http://www.website.com/en/pages/1APPLES
http://www.website.com/en/APPLES
```

**Attempted RegEx Patterns** (well, at least the *best* attempts)

```
(http://*.*.website*.*.com/*.*/pages(/APPLES)|(/ORANGES)[\?]*.*)
(http://*.*.website*.*.com/*.*/pages(/APPLES|/ORANGES)[\?]*.*)
```

If you're curious, I intentionally want to allow any sub-domain, suffix after "website" (for different environments), and any path between .com/ and /pages, hence the use of *.* in a number of places.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

**Edit: Final Answer**

My final answer was merged from mathematical.coffee and fardjad.

```
^https?://.*\.website\b.*\.com/.*/pages/(APPLES\b|ORANGES\b)((\?\w+=\w+)(&?\w+=\w+)*)?$
```

The single limitation I've discovered is that it will not allow a few valid characters (.~_-%+) in the query string parameter key=value pairs (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Structure). This isn't an issue for me as I'm matching against a string returned from .NET's Uri class, so I know the URL is well-formed overall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `*.*` should be `.*`:

```
http://.*\.website\b.*\.com/.*/pages/PAGE[12](\?[^=]+=[^&=]+(&[^=]+=[^=&]+)*)?
```

Explanation:

```
http://      # just http://
.*\.         # any thing, just make sure it's followed by '.'
website\b    # website, the whole word
.*\.com      # anything between website and .com
/.*/pages/   # anything between the .com and the pages
PAGE[12]     # PAGE1 or PAGE2
(\?          # opening bracket and '?' (query string)
[^=]+        # the key: i've said it can't include =
=            # =
[^=&]+       # the value: i've said it can't include = or &
(&           # opening bracket and '&' for next part of query string
[^=]+=[^=&]+ # key=value pair, same regex as before
)*           # 0 or more of these (the &key=value)
)?           # the entire query string is optional.
```

NOTE - there are usually problems parsing query strings with regex and making sure it's a syntactically valid regex.

For example, in the regex I supplied above, I've said that the value in &key=value can't have an ampersand in it. But it could be an escaped entity, like `&amp;`, which *is* legal.

You'll always suffer from this sort of problem when you try to parse syntax with regex. It's a risk you'll have to take.

Alternatively, I am sure there is a C# module to parse URLs (many other languages have these), and they take care of all these special cases for you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Really appreciate the detailed breakdown of what your pattern does :) I was using PAGE1 and PAGE2 as placeholders, in reality I have two different words (e.g. APPLE, ORANGE); sorry for not being clear on that point. I've updated my question to reflect that. I tried modifying your pattern as follows, but I'm missing something as it isn't matching correctly.

`code`http://.*\.website\b.*\.com/.*/pages/APPLES\b|ORANGES\b(\?[^=]+=[^&=]+(&[^=]+=[^=&]+)*)?

Comment: You have to add brackets around the alternation: `(APPLES|ORANGES)`.

Comment: Awesome, got it all working. Your pattern didn't filter out all my bad URLs, so I mixed and matched snippets of your pattern and the one from @fardjad until all my tests passed. Only minor issue that I'm not too worried about is that I can't have a few allowed characters in the query parameters, but since I'm matching against a string returned from a .NET URI, it should be fine. Final pattern: `code`^https?://.*\.website\b.*\.com/.*/pages/(APPLES\b|ORANGES\b)((\?\w+=\w+)(&?\w+=\w+)*)?$

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://regexr.com?30917):

```
^https?://(www\.)?\w+[^/]+(/\w+(?=/)){2}/(PAGE1|PAGE2)((\?\w+=\w+)(&?\w+=\w+)*)?$
```