# How to get route data keys from url parameter in custom Route constructor via Regex?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, regex

Basically, I need to get an array of route value keys from a route string. Regex is looking like the way, but I can't seem to get the regex down.

From `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"`

To a `string[]` with values, `"controller", "action", "id"`

Here's the closest I got `Regex.Split(url, "/{(.*?)}/");`

But I'm getting unusual results: `"{controller}", "action", "{id}"`

Comment: To clarify your question, are you attempting to use *Regular Expressions* to modify the URL Path?  If that is the case, take a look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628857/regex-pattern-for-partial-url-switch-on-two-values-in-path

Comment: Are you running the regex against `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"` or are you actually running it against what the regex will see from the URL, that is `"controller/action/id"`? I ask because curly brackets aren't ever going to be in your URL (I hope).

Comment: @mr.smors: He wants to parse the route pattern.  The routing framework already does this, but doesn't expose it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably alot cheaper to avoid Regex. Try:

```
var myRoute = "{controller}/{action}/{id}";
string[] results = myRoute.Split(new[] { '{', '}', '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can call `someContext.RouteData.Values.Keys.ToArray()`, where someContext can be `RequestContext`, for example. Make sure that you import System.Linq namespace to get `ToArray()` extension method.

If you want to do it through an action you will need to do it through ControllerContext. For example,

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var routeDataKeys = ControllerContext.RouteData.Values.Keys.ToArray();
    var content = String.Empty;

    foreach (var key in routeDataKeys)
    {
        content += "   " + key;
    }
    return Content(content);
}
```

You will get all the keys that belong to the currently chosen Route without curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

No need for regex:

```
List<string> parts = str.Split('/').Select(p => p.Trim(new []{ '}', '{' })).ToList();
```

Comment: More complex than needed. No need for LINQ projections or ToList() forced enumerations.